# No module named tensor flow -- iPython notebook

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I understand this may be an old question, but still I cannot find solution from off-the-shelf Q$A. Here is the problem:

I am following **Udacity** "Machine Learning" and its assignments, and need use ***iPythonNotebook & tensorflow***. Details : https://github.com/Omarito2412/udacity-deeplearning

Assignment2 requires tensorflow. BTW, I already **installed Anaconda**,
already made **tensorflow working on Pycharm** on the same computer which is **Macbook**, but do not know how to make it work on iPythonNotebook environment.

The codes are quite simple, as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from six.moves import cPickle as pickle
from six.moves import range
```

---

### and the error message is as follows:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-0970743dd90d> in <module>()
      2 # before proceeding further.
      3 import numpy as np
----> 4 import tensorflow as tf
      5 from six.moves import cPickle as pickle
      6 from six.moves import range

ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

Thanks. Any suggestions ?

PS: I have this problem on two MacBooks, and both MacBooks run Pycharm+tensorflow well.

Comment: try this： https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/647#issuecomment-291819290

Answer (score 4):

You should deactivate and re-activate the environment

```
source deactivate tensorflow
source activate tensorflow
```

Comment: Please don't post [identical answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41229524) to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Answer (score 3):

After I tried Anaconda-installation (I was using the other installation methods, which are all shown in the link below)
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#anaconda-installation
It worked ...

Further, on terminal activate tensorflow

```
>>> source activate tensorflow
```

before open iPython Notebook

```
>>> ipython notebook
```

At last, I have to restart my macbook to make it work....

Answer (score 1):

i have missed tensorflow install (3) number below the list..
 now i have solved

1. for anaconda install
2. for enviroment install
   https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#anaconda-installation
3. for tensorflow install
   https://github.com/conda-forge/tensorflow-feedstock

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to an anemic environment variable, one of the library path class.  I don't know how iPythonNotebook denotes the libraries it will search for files (say, $LD_LIBRARY_PATH), but I believe that you have to find it (a list of paths to libraries) and add the root directory of TensorFlow.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely either Tensorflow is not installed in the right Python environment of Conda or not installed at all. Follow the below steps:

```
$ conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5
```

Once that is done, need to activate that as below:

```
$ source activate tensorflow
```

Then when you open IPython Notebook or Spyder, it will recognize the Tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

Run `python -m ipykernel install --user --name <Environment_Name>`. This should add your environment to the jupyter kernel list.

Change the kernel using `Kernel->Change Kernel` option or `New-><Environment_Name>`.