# Module is not found when trying to import it and running a virtual environment (venv)

Tags: python, module, python-import, importerror, python-venv

I am currently using a virtual environment (venv) with python. The "venv" directory is inside my project folder by standard convention.

My project folder contains multiple different modules.

I have a jupyter notebook that has multiple import statements in the beginning. One of the import statements calls one of my other custom-made modules. This certain module imports tensorflow. When I call `pip3 list -V` in the terminal, I get:

```
Package                 Version
----------------------- ---------
absl-py                 0.13.0
anyio                   3.3.0
appnope                 0.1.2
argon2-cffi             20.1.0
astunparse              1.6.3
attrs                   21.2.0
autopep8                1.5.7
Babel                   2.9.1
backcall                0.2.0
bleach                  4.0.0
cachetools              4.2.2
certifi                 2021.5.30
cffi                    1.14.6
charset-normalizer      2.0.4
cycler                  0.10.0
debugpy                 1.4.1
decorator               5.0.9
defusedxml              0.7.1
entrypoints             0.3
gast                    0.3.3
google-auth             1.34.0
google-auth-oauthlib    0.4.5
google-pasta            0.2.0
grpcio                  1.39.0
h5py                    2.10.0
idna                    3.2
ipykernel               6.2.0
ipython                 7.26.0
ipython-genutils        0.2.0
ipywidgets              7.6.3
jedi                    0.18.0
Jinja2                  3.0.1
json5                   0.9.6
jsonschema              3.2.0
jupyter-client          6.1.12
jupyter-core            4.7.1
jupyter-server          1.10.2
jupyterlab              3.1.7
jupyterlab-pygments     0.1.2
jupyterlab-server       2.7.0
jupyterlab-widgets      1.0.0
Keras-Preprocessing     1.1.2
kiwisolver              1.3.1
Markdown                3.3.4
MarkupSafe              2.0.1
matplotlib              3.4.3
matplotlib-inline       0.1.2
mistune                 0.8.4
nbclassic               0.3.1
nbclient                0.5.4
nbconvert               6.1.0
nbformat                5.1.3
nest-asyncio            1.5.1
notebook                6.4.3
numpy                   1.18.5
oauthlib                3.1.1
opt-einsum              3.3.0
packaging               21.0
pandocfilters           1.4.3
parso                   0.8.2
pexpect                 4.8.0
pickleshare             0.7.5
Pillow                  8.3.1
pip                     21.2.4
prometheus-client       0.11.0
prompt-toolkit          3.0.19
protobuf                3.17.3
ptyprocess              0.7.0
pyasn1                  0.4.8
pyasn1-modules          0.2.8
pycodestyle             2.7.0
pycparser               2.20
Pygments                2.10.0
pyparsing               2.4.7
pyrsistent              0.18.0
python-dateutil         2.8.2
pytz                    2021.1
pyzmq                   22.2.1
requests                2.26.0
requests-oauthlib       1.3.0
requests-unixsocket     0.2.0
rsa                     4.7.2
scipy                   1.4.1
Send2Trash              1.8.0
setuptools              49.2.1
six                     1.16.0
sniffio                 1.2.0
tensorboard             2.6.0
tensorboard-data-server 0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit  1.8.0
tensorflow              2.3.0
tensorflow-estimator    2.3.0
termcolor               1.1.0
terminado               0.11.0
testpath                0.5.0
toml                    0.10.2
tornado                 6.1
traitlets               5.0.5
urllib3                 1.26.6
wcwidth                 0.2.5
webencodings            0.5.1
websocket-client        1.2.1
Werkzeug                2.0.1
wheel                   0.37.0
widgetsnbextension      3.5.1
wrapt                   1.12.1
```

However, when I try to import my module that contains tensorflow I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'`. We can clearly see that tensorflow has been installed by pip3. What's my problem here?

I am new to programming in general and would appreciate some guidance here. I have looked into the PYTHONPATH variable and am trying to understand it. I am also confused with this since I am implementing a virtual environment here. I am using MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

You may be running your jupyter notebook from a different virtual environment. So if you are running jupyter from conda, you need to shut it down, and start jupyter server from terminal with your venv:

```
jupyter notebook
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been doing.

Comment: So you have 2 options to do:

1. install tensorflow and all modules you need to conda environment (`conda install tensorflow`)

2. Close conda, terminate jupyter and run a jupyter server from your venv

Comment: I'm not using conda. I'm using venv. I also can't use conda for this project since I need tensorflow 2.3 specifically and conda does not have it in their package repo.

Comment: If you just run `import tensorflow` in your notebook, will you have the same error?

Comment: Are you sure you installed packages in your venv? Did you activate venv before installing?  
If yes, then are you sure you are running jupyter from this activated environment?

Comment: Yes. I installed the packages with my virtual environment activated. Before running jupyter, I also activate my virtual environment. I'm certain that this is probably a PATH issue.

Comment: If you write a simple test.py, where you import tensorflow and print its version and run it from your terminal with venv activated, will you see this error again? If you see tensorflow's version, then maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/43967691/7480183 But if you are still getting the error, it looks like this: https://realpython.com/lessons/why-cant-python-find-my-modules/#description