# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I got this error in Jupyter Notebook.

this may duplicate post but no any proper answer found

**Neither below links helped me to solve this.**

[No module named tensorflow in jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221181/no-module-named-tensorflow-in-jupyter)

[No module named tensor flow -- iPython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756452/no-module-named-tensor-flow-ipython-notebook)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b88de1945047> in <module>()
      1 get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')
      2 import numpy as np
----> 3 import tensorflow as tf
      4 from tensorflow.contrib import rnn
      5 import data_loader

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

B:S - [image: python and anaconda version screenshot]

Comment: This error message usually means that TensorFlow is not installed. Have you run `pip install tensorflow` (or `pip install tensorflow-gpu` for the GPU version)?

Comment: I tried pip3 install tensorflow since I have the python 3 is installed default via Anaconda installtion

Comment: Can you add the output from running `pip3 show tensorflow` to your question?

Comment: https://ibb.co/j7HuNv

Comment: Hey I did pip install tensorflow, now it's working for Python3. How that happened ? so no need pip3 install tensorflow for work with Python3 ?

Comment: I'm guessing that you had more than one virtualenv/Anaconda environment, and TensorFlow was installed in one of them but not the one you were using for Jupyter.

Comment: it's now working on Jupyter notebook as well !!

Comment: Now I am having error for data_loader module. "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data_loader'". I installed it via pip but the error remains still. https://ibb.co/ePFJhv

Comment: Use `which pip` and `which python` to see if both point to the same python installation.

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuIUq.png)

I faced the same problem at first. I realized that in the conda-->envs -->
    tensorflow-->Scripts-->idle.exe, is the python 3.5.5 shell. Where you can   import tensorflow without any problems. So, I chaged the directory as C:\Users\Temp\Anconda3..... and then activated and deactived the tensorflow once. In the next step I entered the python mode and import tensorflow as tf worked right.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or error messages, post the text directly here on SO instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I think I've found the solution! 
See, I had installed both CPU and GPU versions of Tensorflow at the same time which apparently is wrong. Then, I uninstalled the GPU version, it didn't work this time either. So I uninstalled both of them and reinstalled the CPU version. It's working now.

BTW I'm on Win10(1803) and python 3.6.5 (not using anaconda.)

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the following instructions and command to solve the issue: (do not include inverted commas)

1. Open Anaconda Prompt
2. type: "create --name py3-TF2.0 python = 3"
3. press "y" to continue

After successful completion:

4. type "conda activate py3-TF2.0"
5. type "pip install matplotlib"
6. type "pip install tensorflow==2.1.0"
7. type "conda deactivate"
8. type "pip install ipykernel"
9. type "conda install nb_conda_kernels"

Now exit the Anaconda prompt and open the Anaconda Navigator application. Switch to "py3-TF2.0" from the base environment using the Environment tab. Install Jupyter in the specified environment.
After successful installation, open Jupyter notebook and switch to "py3-TF2.0" kernel using Kernel Tab.
You're good to go for using TensorFlow 2.

Make Sure you use Anaconda 2020.02 or lower version.
As new version does not support TensorFlow 2.